# Compiler error by pattern matching dynamic variable

Tags: c#, dynamic, pattern-matching

Why adding `c != null &&`  results to compiler error CS0165 for `c1`? Target is .NET5.0.

```
var a = "";
if(a is string a1)
{
    if("".Contains(a1)) return; //OK
}
dynamic b = "";
if(b is string b1)
{
    if("".Contains(b1)) return; //OK
}

dynamic c = "";
if(c != null && c is string c1)
{
    if("".Contains(c1)) return; //CS0165 Using not assigned variable??
}

dynamic d = "";
if(d != null && d is string)
{
    var d1 = d;
    if("".Contains(d1)) return; //OK

    var d11 = d as string;
    if("".Contains(d11)) return; //OK
}
```

**Update:**
**So according to the answer of Luaan the whole statement will not be evaluated, not only on right side from dynamic object**.

```
dynamic d = "";
var c = "";
if(c is string c1 && true && d != null && c is string f1)
{
    if("".Contains(c1)) return; //error
                
    if("".Contains(f1)) return; //error

    var d1 = d;
    if("".Contains(d1)) return; //OK
    var d11 = d as string;
    if("".Contains(d11)) return; //OK
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` doesn't short-circuit in compile-time on dynamic operands.

As per the spec ([Conditional logical operators](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/spec/expressions.md#conditional-logical-operators)):

> If an operand of a conditional logical operator has the compile-time type dynamic, then the expression is dynamically bound (Dynamic binding). In this case the compile-time type of the expression is dynamic, and the resolution described below will take place at run-time using the run-time type of those operands that have the compile-time type dynamic.

`c != null && c is string c1` is a dynamic expression, so it's dynamic bound, and the static compiler cannot ensure `c1` is assigned.

Of course, it doesn't really matter in practice, since your null-check is entirely superfluous - `is string` already ensures the value isn't null.

Comment: But if it doesn't shortcricuit, then c1 would be always assigned... I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @InBetween the `&&` can return `true` without evaluating the RHS

Comment: So you mean, that if in a conditional logical operator there is a dynamic object, then __all declared in statement variables__ will be seen as not assigned? Correct?

Comment: Can you provide an example where the compiler is right?

Comment: See the ever-clear [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/) on this topic

Comment: @Rekshino `dynamic` is infectious. The compiler never knows what `dynamic` could possibly be, so unless you constrain it severely, you get a lot of issues. If the compiler allowed you to do this, it would potentially violate the memory safety guarantees, which would be very, very bad.

Comment: @canton7: thanks, that i was searching. That class is really `Crazy` and shows that it's possible to have such a type

Comment: I'm trying to find the question mentioned in that article, to close this as a dup, and utterly failing...

Comment: Well, but then this answer is kind of misleading isnt it? It says that the expression is dynamic hence it cannot be ensured that `c1` is assigned at compile time. Isn't the right answer that just the dynamic type of  `c` is the problem since it could be such a weird type that actually `c1` keeps unassigned?

Comment: @TimSchmelter But that's exactly what causes the whole expression to be dynamic dynamic. If you restrict the types, e.g. use `(object)c != null` or `(bool)(c != null)`, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the compiler can not verify in any way that the logical operators are not overloaded in some weird way that happens to never evaluate the right hand side of the logical expression while still succesfully returning `true`. That is the reason why you get the compile time error.

Comment: Yes i think this is the answer, but i'm waiting for an example. How you cam prevent evaluating the right hand side? You cannot overload the `&&` operator

Comment: @TimSchmelter I seem to recall Eric Lippert talking about this issue... true that the setup is convoluted and I'm probably unable to come up with an example, but I'd bet the underlying issue is some really messed up logical operator overloading.

Comment: Canton7 has posted what i was searching, the class `Crazy`: https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/